# ¿Cómo ocultar el valor de un vector impresa en un tablero en consola Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, consola

Buenas noches. 
Estoy haciendo una tarea de la Universidad que consiste básicamente en un buscaminas. Me he topado con el problema de que al imprimir en la consola el tablero que define mi Buscaminas también me imprime la posición de mis minas y sabrán que eso no debería funcionar de esa forma. Lo que busco es la forma de ocultar esos valores y solamente mostrarlos cuando el usuario ingrese la coordenada en el teclado.

Mi tablero lo imprimo de esta forma:

```
   public void tableroI() {

    System.out.println("\n***********************");
    System.out.println("N = mina normal");
    System.out.println("A = mina amigable");
    System.out.println("L = mina letal");
    System.out.println("D = mina dorada");
    System.out.println("***********************\n");

    for (x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {

            tablero[x][y] = "0";
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.print("_" + tablero[x][y] + "_");

        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }

}

public void tablero() {


    for (x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {

            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.print("_" + tablero[x][y] + "_");

        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }

}
```

Verán que tengo dos tableros, el tableroI() me muestra solo valores de 0 antes de comenzar y el tablero() me muestra esos mismo ceros con la salvedad que ya me muestra también la posición aleatoria de mis minas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las vacías son porque especifiqué que si la coordenada es "0" muestra "Vacio" pero al hacer cualquier coordenada ya me muestran los valores de las minas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Básicamente solo debe mostrar la mina encontrada y lo demás en blanco hasta que seleccione esa coordenada.

```
 public void Llenar() {

    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        int x = r.nextInt(15);
        int y = r.nextInt(5);

        valor = (int) (Math.random()*4+1);
        tablero[x][y] = String.valueOf(valor);

     //   System.out.println("Posición: " + "(" + (x + 1) + "," + (y + 1) + ") = " + valor);

    }
  //  System.out.println("\n");

}
```

Con éstas líneas de código estoy creando de forma aleatoria mi posición y el valor del mismo.

Entonces lo único que necesito es ocultar esos números y solamente mostrar las letras que correspondan a al tipo de mina. Espero haber sido claro y gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

La manera más sencilla que tienes para resolver ese problema es guardando en una matriz auxiliar si la casilla debe ser mostrada o no, esta matriz podría ser declarada del siguiente modo:

```
boolean[][] auxiliar = new boolean[15][5];
```

Yo modificaría el siguiente método que tienes:

```
for (x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {

        System.out.print("|");
        if(auxiliar[x][y] == true){
            System.out.print("_" + tablero[x][y] + "_");
        }else{
            System.out.print("_0_");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("|");
}
```

Y en el momento que capturas las coordenadas que el usuario selecciona cambiar el valor en auxiliar a true, y si este se encuentra ya con ese valor que no pase nada y volvamos a pedir las coordenadas al usuario